# How can my object value change within the iteration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Excuse me if this is a stupid question
I am trying to do below.

This is my action:

```
public JsonResult CumLeadsParameters(CumLeadsReport cumLeads)
{
    var weeks = (cumLeads.EndDate - cumLeads.StartDate).TotalDays / 7;

    if (!(weeks > 0))
    {
        // means I have less than a week so calculate days and make it as a weeek and 
        var startDate = new DateTime(cumLeads.StartDate.Year,
                                     cumLeads.StartDate.Month,
                                     cumLeads.StartDate.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var ts = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
        var endDate = startDate.AddDays(6.0).Date + ts;
        var x = _retailerStatsRepository.GetAllRetailersForManufacturerCountrySelectedDates(
                    manufacturer.Id,
                    country.Id,
                    startDate,
                    endDate);
    }
    else
    {
        cumLeads.StartDate = new DateTime(cumLeads.StartDate.Year,
                                          cumLeads.StartDate.Month,
                                          cumLeads.StartDate.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        while (weeks > 0)
        {
            weekCounter++;
            var ts = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
            cumLeads.EndDate = cumLeads.StartDate.AddDays(6.0).Date + ts;
            var x = _retailerStatsRepository.GetAllRetailersForManufacturerCountrySelectedDates(
                        manufacturer.Id,
                        country.Id,
                        cumLeads.StartDate,
                        cumLeads.EndDate);

            tuple.Add(new Tuple<int, IQueryable<RetailerStat>, DateTime, DateTime>(
                weekCounter,
                x,
                cumLeads.StartDate,
                cumLeads.EndDate));
        }
    }
}
```

/* Note*/

For example I have passed date `cumLeads.StartDate` and `cumLeads.EndDate` as `2013-08-01 to 2013-08-12`
Then my while condition is satisfied twice  and when second time it enter into loop I don't want date to be set back to `01/08/2013` as my `startdate` I want it as `08/08/2013 00:00:00:000`.

Any advices will be helpful.

Comment: would putting `cumLeads.StartDate=cumLeads.StartDate.AddDays(6.0).Date+ts` at the end of the loop not work?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here.  There does't appear to be a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few clean up things I noticed. Note that I formatted your code to look more legible on this site, I did not mean to imply the above changes are things you should do (the following are what I would recommend).

- `!(weeks > 0)` would be better as `weeks <= 0`
- `new DateTime` has an overload that takes `year, month, day`
- Even better, `.Date` returns a new `DateTIme` with just those parameters.
- `startDate.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1)` is a more compact version of your logic. Note that `.Date` is redundant since you already specified it was a date.

To answer your question, you aren't updating `cumLeads.StartDate` anywhere, if you wanted it to change you would need to update it. I can't tell what you are trying to do so simply went with an implementation of my points above.

```
public JsonResult CumLeadsParameters(CumLeadsReport cumLeads)
{
    var weeks = (cumLeads.EndDate - cumLeads.StartDate).TotalDays / 7;

    if (!(weeks > 0))
    {
        // means I have less than a week so calculate days and make it as a weeek and 
        var startDate = cumLeads.StartDate.Date;
        var endDate = startDate.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1);
        var x = _retailerStatsRepository.GetAllRetailersForManufacturerCountrySelectedDates(
                    manufacturer.Id,
                    country.Id,
                    startDate,
                    endDate);
    }
    else
    {
        cumLeads.StartDate = cumLeads.StartDate.Date;
        while (weeks > 0)
        {
            weekCounter++;
            cumLeads.EndDate = cumLeads.StartDate.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1);
            var x = _retailerStatsRepository.GetAllRetailersForManufacturerCountrySelectedDates(
                        manufacturer.Id,
                        country.Id,
                        cumLeads.StartDate,
                        cumLeads.EndDate);

            tuple.Add(new Tuple<int, IQueryable<RetailerStat>, DateTime, DateTime>(
                weekCounter,
                x,
                cumLeads.StartDate,
                cumLeads.EndDate));
        }
    }
}
```